# Conservativity of stalks of ind-constructible sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, constructible-sheaves

I have a simple question about the conservativity of stalks of ind-constructible sheaves. Let $X$ be a topologically noetherian scheme, $S$ a set of geometric points of $X$ corresponding bijectively to the scheme-theoretic points of $X$, $\Lambda$ an algebraic extension of $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$ or the ring of integers of such, $I$ a filtered category (which I will assume is a directed poset), $\operatorname{Cons}_X(\Lambda)$ the abelian category of constructible $\Lambda$-sheaves on $X_{\text{pro-étale}}$ in the sense of Bhatt-Scholze §6.8, and let $(\mathcal F_i)_{i\in I}$ correspond to a functor $I\to \operatorname{Cons}_X(\Lambda)$ with colimit $\mathcal F$ computed in $\operatorname{Mod}(X_{\text{pro-étale}},\Lambda)$, the category of sheaves of $\Lambda$-modules, where $\Lambda$ here and often below also denotes the sheaf $\Lambda_X$ associated to the topological ring $\Lambda$.

**My question is,** if $\mathcal F_x=0$ for every $x\in S$, is $\mathcal F=0$?
(Here $\mathcal F_x:=\Gamma(x_{\text{pro-étale}},x^*\mathcal F$.)

I believe I can prove this is true (argument below), but what is giving me some doubts is Warning 2.3.4.10 of the paper *Weil’s conjecture for function fields* [[PDF](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/tamagawa-abridged.pdf)], which says that there is a non-zero ind-constructible sheaf which vanishes at all closed points. This is relevant since Corollary 3.51 of the recent paper [*Constructible sheaves on schemes and a categorical Künneth formula*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.02853) connects $\operatorname{Ind}(D_{\mathrm{cons}}(X,\Lambda))$ to filtered colimits of pro-étale sheaves. Admittedly, this warning only deals with closed points, but so far I haven’t been able to construct a non-zero ind-constructible sheaf that vanishes at all closed points. Here is my purported (simple) ‘proof’ that the answer to my question is ‘yes’:

**Proof**
It would suffice to show that for every $i\in I$, there is a $j\geq i$ so
that $\varphi_{ij}:\mathcal F_i\to\mathcal F_j$ is zero.
Suppose we could find a nonempty open $U\subset X$ over which this is true.
Then we could replace $i$ by $j$ and $X$ by
$\operatorname{supp}\operatorname{coker}(\ker\varphi_{ij}\to\mathcal F_i)$, and we'd be done by
noetherian induction.

To find $U$: let $\eta$ be a geometric generic point of $X$. We can find a
$j\geq i$ so that $\varphi_{ij}:\mathcal F_i\to\mathcal F_j$ induces zero on
stalks at $\eta.^\dagger$ There is some connected neighborhood $U$ of
$\eta$ so that both $\mathcal F_i$ and $\mathcal F_j$ are locally constant
of finite presentation over $U$.
Then the same is true of $\ker\varphi_{ij}$, and as
$(\ker\varphi_{ij})_\eta=(\mathcal F_i)_\eta$,
$\ker\varphi_{ij}|_U=\mathcal F_i|_U.^\ddagger$
$\square$

$\dagger$: Both $\eta^*$ and $\Gamma(\eta_\text{pro-étale},-)$ commute with colimits,
the latter since $\eta$ is connected and w-contractible.
For each $i$, there is some neighborhood $U_i$ of $\eta$ restricted to which
$\mathcal F_i$ is (pro-étale) locally of the form
$M_i\otimes_\Lambda\Lambda_X$, where $M$ is a
$\Lambda$-module of finite presentation and I've dropped the underlines for
constant sheaves ($\Lambda_X$ is not literally a constant sheaf).
(This is what I mean by ‘locally constant of finite presentation.’)
Note $(M_i\otimes_\Lambda\Lambda_X)_\eta=M_i$ as $\Lambda_X(\eta)=\Lambda$
and $\eta$ is w-contractible.

$\ddagger$: When $\Lambda$ is a field, this follows from Corollary 6.8.5 of [BS] and that $(-)_x$ is an exact functor (of abelian categories).
Otherwise, modulo possibly shrinking $U$, replace Corollary 6.8.5 with Proposition 6.8.11.

It remains unclear to me how this doesn’t contradict Warning 2.3.4.10. Thanks for any clarification of the matter.

Comment: Is this direct for ind-lisse sheaves? My understanding is poor, but it seems that stratified versions are not too different from non-stratified versions.

Comment: There is no contradiction yet, right? Gaitsgory–Lurie only talk about stalks at *closed* points, and indicate (without any details) that this is not enough, and that the problem is related to $\ell$-completeness. Of course it would have been much better if they gave an actual example instead of a claim without any details ― you could write to them to ask for clarification.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn And seemingly, G–L does not say that there are counterexamples for ind-constructible sheaves.

Comment: @Z.M I think their $\ell$-adic sheaves are by definition ind-constructible; see Definition 2.3.4.1. (To some extent, this is the most intuitive notion, as any usual étale sheaf is a filtered colimit of constructible ones. I don't know if $\operatorname{Ind}(X_{\text{ét}}^{\text{cons}}) \to X_{\text{ét}}$ is an equivalence, but I suspect not.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks. The last equivalence seems to hold, which is mentioned by OP: [ [Remo–Richarz–Scholbach](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.02853), Rem 3.52], also in Bhatt–Scholze.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how related this is with the ind-sheaf framework of Kashiwara-Schapira, but this question is emphasized several times in their 2001 book ["Ind-Sheaves"](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Epierre.schapira/BooksMono/AstIndSh.pdf) ( e.g.: examples 4.2.17 & 4.2.18, 4.3.20, and exercise 4.8).

They define a notion of the "ind-stalk" of an ind-sheaf $K \in I(k_X) := Ind(Mod^c(k_X))$ at a point $x \in X$, denoted ${}_x K$ (in Section 4.3), and prove in **Proposition 4.3.21** exactly the type of result you seem to be looking for: If $f: L \to K$ is a morphism of ind-sheaves of $k_X$-modules for which the induced morphism on ind-stalks ${}_x f: {}_x L \to {}_x K$ is zero for all $x \in X$, then $f$ is the zero morphism.

Comment: I don't think that it is the same. Kashiwara–Schapira does not seem to impose constructibility.